# How Can I Insert Data to Mongodb From String in Dotnet Core

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, .net-core

I am newbie in dotnet and mongodb world.I am fetching a json string form an api and i want to insert them to mongodb.Assume that we have this string:

```
string json = "{'a': '5e7629e5ca467a22e9464c6f'},{'a': '5e7629e5744c85ffb94de085'}";
```

This string contains 2 document in my view.I want to insert mongodb as 2 document.But if i try to insert them like this:

```
collection.InsertOne(json);
```

it is inserting as 1 document all of them.
I think should serialize the string then insert documents one by one.

How can i achieve insert string to MongoDB as multiple documents?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [collection.insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#db.collection.insertMany) ... "If you have a need to insert multiple documents at the same time, MongoDB has you covered there as well with the InsertMany or InsertManyAsync methods."

Comment: No this is mongo shell command.I am looking for mongodb c# driver.

Comment: So you didn't even try to see of `InsertMany()` is available or anything like it??  [Quick Start: C# and MongoDB - Creating Documents](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-sharp-and-mongodb--creating-documents)... Look down to "Create Operation" it states "If you have a need to insert multiple documents at the same time, MongoDB has you covered there as well with the InsertMany or InsertManyAsync methods." -- Pretty unresourceful.

Comment: I've already resourced it.But here, problem is i have a json string and i can not insert many with a json string.I should convert it to bson objects for every json document.But even if i serialize it from string insertmany() method is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BsonDocument.Parse(your_json_string)`. Then you will be able using `collection.InsertMany..`